# Is there a way to install both debug and release version of flutter app without changing the App ID?

Tags: android, flutter

I just build a release version of my app but later on, I found that entering debug mode with *flutter run* will uninstall the release version of my app since they share the same id, assigning debug version of my app with another id is rather uncomfortable since I must change it in many different places it also possible that I forget to change it again later in the next release.

Is it possible to have both debug and release version of my app without changing its ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way for run debug and release mode as one app without changing package name.

but you can use flutter flavor to run different configuration apps.

find out official documentation [from here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors)